# OCaml directed graphs vertex module

Tags: graph, module, ocaml, vertex, directed-graph

I have seen some graphs vertex signatures and even come up with my own:

```
module type VERTEX = sig
    type t
    type label

    val equal : t -> t -> bool
    val create : label -> t
    val label : t -> label  
end
```

But I have completely no idea how to implement it as a module. What types should t and label be? How can I create a t based on a label? And how do I get the label from a t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a module based on a signature is like a mini puzzle. Here's how I would analyze it:

The first remark I have when reading that signature, is that there is no way in that signature to build values of type `label`. So, our implementation will need to be a bit larger, maybe by specifying `type label = string`.

Now, we have:

```
val create : label -> t
val label : t -> label
```

Which is a bijection (the types are "equivalent"). The simplest way to implement that is by defining `type t = label`, so that it's really only one type, but from the exterior of the module you don't know that.

The rest is

```
type t
val equal: t -> t -> bool
```

We said that `label = string`, and `t = label`. So `t = string`, and `equal` is the string equality.

Boom! here we are:

```
module String_vertex : VERTEX with type label = string = struct
  type label = string
  type t = string

  let equal = String.equal

  let create x = x
  let label x = x
end
```

The `VERTEX with type label = string` part is just if you want to define it in the same file. Otherwise, you can do something like:

```
(* string_vertex.ml *)
type label = string
type t = string

let equal = String.equal

let create x = x
let label x = x
```

and any functor F that takes a `VERTEX` can be called with `F(String_vertex)`.
It would be best practice to create `string_vertex.mli` with contents `include VERTEX with type label = string`, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an author of [Graphlib](http://opam.ocaml.org/packages/graphlib/), so I can't pass by as this question hits me directly into my heart. Honestly, I was asked this question millions of times offline and never was able to provide a good answer.

The real problem is that the graph interfaces from the [OCamlGraph](http://opam.ocaml.org/packages/ocamlgraph/) library are all messed up. We started Graphlib as an attempt to fix them. However, OCamlGraph is a valuable repository of Graph algorithms, thus we have constrained ourselves to be compatible with the OCamlGraph interface. The main problem for us was and still is this Vertex interface that basically establishes a bijection between the set of labels and the set of nodes. People usually stumble on this, as this doesn't make sense - why do we need two different types, one for the label and another for the vertex, if they are the same?

Indeed, the simplest implementation of the `VERTEX` interface is the following module

```
module Int : VERTEX with type label = int = struct
  type t = int
  type label = int
  let create x = x 
  let label x = x
end
```

In that case, we indeed have a trivial bijection (via the identity endofunctor) between the set of labels and the set of vertices.

However, the deeper look, shows us that a signature

```
val create : label -> t
val label : t -> label
```

Is not really a bijection, as the bijection is a one-to-one mapping. It is not really required or enforced by the type system. For example, the `create` function could be a surjection of `label` onto `t`, where `label` is some distinctive element of a family of vertices. Correspondingly, the `label` function, could be a forgetting functor that returns the distinctive label and forgetting everything else.

Given this approach, we can have another implementation:

```
  module Labeled = struct
    type label = int
    type t = {
      label : label;
      data : "";  
    }

    let create label = {label; data = ""}
    let label n = n.label
    let data n = n.data
    let with_data n data = {n with data}
    let compare x y = compare x.label y.label
  end
```

In that implementation, we use the label as an identity of a node, and arbitrary attribute can be attached to a node. In this interpretation, the `create` function partitions all sets of nodes into a set of [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class), where all members of a class, share the same identity, i.e., they represent the same real-world entity in different points of time or space. For example,

```
type color = Red | Yellow | Green
module TrafficLight = struct 
   type label = int
   type t = {
     id : label;
     color : color
   }

   let create id = {id; color=Red}
   let label t = t.id
   let compare x y = compare x.id y.id
   let switch t color = {t with color}
   let color t = t.color
end
```

In this model, we represent a traffic light with its id number. The color attribute doesn't affect an identity of a traffic light (if a traffic light switches to another color it is still the same traffic light, although in a functional programming language it is represented with two different objects).

The main problem with the above representation is that in all graph textbooks the label is used in the opposite meaning - as an opaque attribute. In a textbook, they will refer to the color of a traffic light as a label. And the node itself will be represented as an int. That's why I'm saying that OCamlGraph interfaces are messed up (and consequently the Graphlib interfaces). So, if you don't want to fall in a contradiction with textbooks, then you should use unlabeled graphs (with `int` probably is the best representation of a node). And if you need to attach attributes to your nodes, you can use external finite maps, i.e., arrays, maps, associative lists, or any other dictionaries. Otherwise, you need to keep in mind that your label is not a label, but vice verse - the node.

With all this said, let's specify a better interface for a graph vertex:

```
module type VERTEX = sig 
  type id
  type label
  type t

  val create : id -> t
  val id : t -> id
  val label : t -> label
  val with_label : t -> label -> label
end
```

The proposed interface is compatible with your interface (and thus with the OCamlGraph), as it is isomorphic modulo renaming (i.e., we renamed `label` to `id`). It also allows us to create efficient unlabeled nodes, where `id = t`, as well as attach arbitrary information to a node without relying on external mappings.